# It doesn't work pass variable from one stage to another and iterate with an each loop

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I need to do an each from a variable obtained with stageDependencies previously.

It doesn't work Pass variable from one stage to another and iterate with an each loop using a split function

What am I doing wrong?

Code:

## task.yml

```
steps:
  - task: Bash@3
    name: env_string
    inputs:
      targetType: 'inline'
      script: |
        environmentsStr='dev,prd'
        echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=environmentsString;isOutput=true]$environmentsStr"
```

## pipeline

```
  - stage: stage1
    jobs:
      - job: job_stage1
        steps:
          - template: tasks.yml

  - stage: stage2
    dependsOn:
      - stage1
    variables:
      - name: envFromVar
        value: 'dev,prd'
      - name: envFromStageDependencies
        value: $[ stageDependencies.stage1.job_stage1.outputs['env_string.environmentsString'] ]

    jobs:
      - job: job_stage2
        steps:   
          - template: stage3.yml
            parameters:
              envFromStageDependencies: $(envFromStageDependencies)
              environmentsFromVar: ${{ variables.envFromVar }}
```

## stage3.yml

```
parameters:
  - name: envFromStageDependencies
    type: string
  - name: environmentsFromVar
    type: string

steps:
  - ${{ each environment in split(parameters.envFromStageDependencies, ',') }}:
    - bash: |
        echo "env ${{ environment }}" # OUTPUT FAIL; (env dev,prd)

  - ${{ each environment in split(parameters.environmentsFromVar, ',') }}:
    - bash: |
        echo "envVar ${{ environment }}" # OUTPUT OK, 2 iterations envVar [dev,prd]
```

## OUTPUT

- BASH -> env dev,prd
- BASH -> envVar dev
- BASH -> envVar prd

Comment: Please start by understanding the difference between *run-time* variables and *compile-time* variables. Run-time variables **are not** available in compile-time expressions, because template compilation happens **before** run-time. Please take a step back and explain what you are trying to accomplish at a high level, because the approach you're taking at the moment **will not work**.

Comment: I don't understand if the variable is received in the last stage, why doesn't the split function inside each separate the string into substrings?

Comment: maybe this issue? https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-devops-docs/issues/12836

Comment: `task.setvariable` creates **runtime** variables. You can't use a runtime variable inside a compile-time expression.

Answer (score 0):

You should change your pipeline YAML like as below:

```yaml
. . .

    jobs:
      - job: job_stage2
        steps:   
          - template: stage3.yml
            parameters:
              environments: ${{ variables.envFromStageDependencies }}
              environmentsFromVar: ${{ variables.envFromVar }}
```

As **`@Daniel Mann`** has mentioned, the template is processed at compile time which is before runtime. So, to pass the variable values into the template, you should use the compile time variable syntax (**`${{ variables.varName }}`**) instead of runtime variable syntax (**`$(varName)`**).

For more details, you can reference the document "[**Understand variable syntax**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#understand-variable-syntax)".

Comment: I have tried using the compile-time variable syntax (${{ variables.varName }}), but the output shows the following error:

/opt/vsts_agent/_work/_temp/8ef1586e-84fb-4a1f-9adf-b36c5953acf0.sh: line 1:
 stageDependencies.stage1.job_stage1.outputs['env_string.environmentsString'] : syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".stage1.job_stage1.outputs['env_string.environmentsString'] ")

Comment: Hi @rbr86, I can reproduce the same issue. It looks like an issue. We will try to report this issue to the related product team.

Comment: @BrightRan-MSFT `task.setvariable` creates *runtime* variables. They can't be looped over in compile-time expressions. That's the core issue here.